# What's the best practice to bind IsEnabled property for a button with selected item in a data grid?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a Data Grid and many buttons for commands on the selected item in the data grid.

These buttons will be hidden or disabled based on properties in the selected item in the grid.

For example: if the selected record IsNew, the button Cancel will be disabled.

What's the best practice to implement a situation like this?

I may implement it in the SelectedItemChange manually like the follwoing:

```
void myGrid_selectedItemChanged(sender, args..)
{
    cancelButton.IsEnabled = SelectedItem.IsNew ; // just an example
}
```

The problem with this approach is that, when the selected item is removed, this event will not be fired.

Or in XAML, bind a dependency property with the control:

```
<!--SelectedItemIsNew is a property in the form and binding it with IsEnabled... -->
<Button x:Name="cancelButton" IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItemIsNew ...}"/>
```

The problem here, I must assign a value to the property to notify the bound control, or in other words what's the code here to change the value of the property ?

Another option!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey, i have the same case some time back, i always do that when ever i bind some data with grid or list in SL/WPF as it is easy and more understandable. why dont you try Binding coustom list to your code?? For examlple.. take and Filed like say String HyperLinkNaviagtion

when you get values fro service then befor assigning list to your grid, iterate on all of your items and assign HyperLinkNaviagtion some value like

```
 if(SomeCondition)
    { 
      // navigaet to google
          HyperLinkNaviagtion ="www.google.com";
    } 
 else 
   { 
     // navigaet to yahoo
       HyperLinkNaviagtion ="www.yahoo.com";
   }
```

and in Xaml, do the following

NavigateUri="{Binding HyperLinkNaviagtion }"

It is don, you can control almost every thing like this =)
this might be not the best but in my case it is easiest and tension free too .

Comment: do let me know if this fits in your case, or u need a code snap .

Comment: Thanks, First: I think this needs the HyperLinkNaviagtion to be Dependency property, Second: I have a problem if the grid when it doesn't have a selected item, it'll not ask the property, and the associated control will still in its previous case.

Answer (score 1):

This must be correct:

```
<Button x:Name="cancelButton" IsEnabled="{Binding IsNew, Source=SelectedItem}"/>
```

The question is, where is your SelectedItem? Is it a property of the DataContext, or a property of your control (or of some list inside your control)?

Edit:
For the Control property, the following should do:

```
<Button x:Name="cancelButton"
        IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItem.IsNew,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MyControl}}"/>
```

Comment: It's a property in the Control.

Answer (score 1):

An MVVM implementation would look something like this...

View model code:

```
public class ParentViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private readonly ICommand cancelCommand;
    private readonly ICollection<ChildViewModel> children;
    private ChildViewModel selectedChild;

    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        this.cancelCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.OnCancel, this.CanCancel);
        this.children = new ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel>();
    }

    public ICommand CancelCommand
    {
        get { return this.cancelCommand; }
    }

    public ICollection<ChildViewModel> Children
    {
        get { return this.children; }
    }

    public ChildViewModel SelectedChild
    {
        get { return this.selectedChild; }
        set
        {
            if (this.selectedChild != value)
            {
                this.selectedChild = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(() => this.SelectedChild);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCancel(object parameter)
    {
        // cancel logic here
    }

    private bool CanCancel(object parameter)
    {
        // can only cancel if there's a child selected
        return this.SelectedChild != null;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedChild}">
    ...
</GridView>

...

<Button Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" Content="Cancel"/>
```

Comment: I didn't talk about what will happen when button be fired, I'm talking about the IsEnabled for the button.

Comment: @Homam - that's what the CanCancel (which should return a Boolean) is for.  An ICommand has a CanExecute property, which is what CanCancel is setting.  If CanExecute is false, the Button is automatically disabled.